cocoapod how to use local path as repo
I can write podspec with spec.source = http file://....xx.zip，and pass by the command pod spec lint.
But when my library depends on another local lib, I don't know how to set the "spec.denpendency=" to let cocoapod find my local depends lib.And if I just set name like "spec.denpendency = 'xxxx','1.0.0'",'pod spec lint command --source' also cannot specify a path? WHAT can i DO now
pod repo add local path is acceptable,but i don't find a way.but not to set up a remote git repo
